# HTML5 Mobile app localization using javascript and PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, localization

I'm creating a HTML5 mobile app that runs on all 3 mobile platforms (Android, iOS a,d Windows Mobile 8). I'm using javascript for localization(https://github.com/eligrey/l10n.js/#readme).

The app works fine on the browser. But when I deploy it on the mobile emulator the localization is not working.

I think the issue is that javascript gets language information from the browser, but in the mobile we run the HTML5 using PhoneGap.

Is there any way that I can enable localization using javascript in PhoeGap.

Comment: If you are using Phonegap, make sure you are reading the culture via [globalization.getLocaleName()](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#globalization.getLocaleName) or `globalization.getPreferredLanguage()` and __not__ the browsers' navigator object, this is always set to "en" on android to my experience. Also, see my post below regarding hyphen/underscore matching pitfall

Comment: Take a look here:  https://github.com/EffEPi/localize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just solved same kind of problem by creating a custom PhoneGap plugins for each platforms that only returns the user's current locale.

for example, on Android, the plugin only checks:

`var message = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();`

and then in Javascript side, when you've got that language name back, eg. `en`, you would use the JSON object that it named after that language. The example of JSON object would look like this:

```
MyApp.Language = en: {
    'Player'  : 'Player',
    'Players' : 'Players',
    'Not Set' : 'Not Set'
},
fi: {
    'Player'  : 'Pelaaja',
    'Players' : 'Pelaajat',
    'Not Set' : 'Ei määritetty'
}
```

The plugin for Android is simple as this:

**JS file**

```
window.localizeMe = {
    getDefaultLocale: function( callback ) {
        cordova.exec(
            callback,
            function(err) {
                callback( 'Error: ' + err.code );
            },
            "LocalizeMe",
            "getDefaultLocale",
            []);
    }
}
```

**Java file**

```
public class LocalizeMe extends CordovaPlugin {
    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals("getDefaultLocale")) {
            String message = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
            this.getDefaultLocale(message, callbackContext);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void getDefaultLocale(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
        if (message != null && message.length() > 0) { 
            callbackContext.success(message);
        } else {
            callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
        }
    }

}
```

**And finally, in your main JS file, you set your app's language:**

```
window.localizeMe.getDefaultLocale( function( result ) {
    if ( result != null && result.length > 0 ) {
        if ( result.toLowerCase().indexOf( 'fi' ) !== -1 ) {
            MyApp.Lang = MyApp.Language.fi;
        } else {
            MyApp.Lang = MyApp.Language.en;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can write your own JavaScript to grab the localisation language. This is the exact same reply I wrote elsewhere on here.

In general, the JavaScript `window.navigator.language` usually works for iOS and newer Androids, but earlier versions of Android have it hardcoded to `en`.

For older Androids I suggest pulling the language parameter out of the UserAgent string (yes sniffing!), e.g.

```
if (navigator && navigator.userAgent && (androidLang = navigator.userAgent.match(/android.*\W(\w\w)-(\w\w)\W/i))) {
   lang = androidLang[1];
}
```

Here, lang might also contain the country code (e.g. 'en-IE') so you might have to remove that also:

```
if (lang.indexOf('-') != -1) lang = lang.substring(0, lang.indexOf('-'));
```

This is what I've used in a recent app, using HTML5 and PhoneGap, and it works fine.

Comment: On my Android 4.4.4 `window.navigator.language` yields `zz-ZZ`.

Answer (score 1):

There's one common pitfall with localisation, maybe this is your problem:
Many devices report locales in the form of `de_DE`, `en_GB`, etc... - note the **underscore**.

l10n (or in my case, [globalize.js](https://github.com/jquery/globalize)) use a **hyphen** to separate language and country - thus no matching culture is found and it comes up with the default fallback.

Put a `console.log` in your app to dump the locale string you are getting, then go the the console and check with `adb logcat` whether this might be the case on your device. Then simply modify the string to allow matching (e.g. `locale.value.replace('_', '-')` )