# Get List of all available language values when calling globalization.getPreferredLanguage

Tags: javascript, cordova, globalization

How can I get all the language strings that comply to the returned value of the success function parameter that is passed when calling:

```
navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
  function (language) {alert('language: ' + language.value + '\n');},
  function () {alert('Error getting language\n');}
);
```

[source](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#globalization.getPreferredLanguage)

When I run this code on my Android devices I get "English", however in some places I read that it returns the name of the language in the original language, for example, it will return '中国的' for Chinese.

I need this returned value in order to change the UI language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use the function [getLocaleName](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/cordova_globalization_globalization.md.html#globalization.getLocaleName) for this, and then use the first two chars given. The values given can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes).

Comment: I prefer the preferred language, because the user might have a US local device, but have Japanese language has the preferred language

Comment: That's why you should use the first two chars, f.e. switzerland has 3 possible languages. So the return would look like fr_\CH or de_\CH. The first two letters specify the language set on the device, and after that follows the actual regional code.
**Edit**: I just realized that linked the wrong list, will change that

Comment: There is some issue with this method, and I don't know how to build a custom plugin to user this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870587/html5-mobile-app-localization-using-javascript-and-phonegap)

Comment: I just implemented it in our own app using cordova 3.0, and it worked perfectly on all devices. What cordova version are you using?

Comment: Yes, it sould. And you have the plugin already installed, otherwise you couldn't run the code posted in your question ;-)