# How to change language of content in Cordova PhoneGap app dynamically?

Tags: android, cordova, localization, cordova-plugins

I want to change the content of Cordova PhoneGap app to other language. Since my app contains quite a bit of dynamic data to be loaded, how can I apply the language change?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is. Use with the help of localization you can set different languages for the text. Below are the few links which will help you out

1. [i18n](http://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.1/developer_guides/i18n/)
2. [Localize](https://localizejs.com/docs/integrations/phonegap)
3. [Globalize](https://github.com/jquery/globalize)
4. [Create custom plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870587/html5-mobile-app-localization-using-javascript-and-phonegap)
5. [Custom pages as per language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878002/phonegap-cordova-internationalization-support)
6. [phonegap-l10n](https://github.com/plang/phonegap-l10n)

Key here is to know which language or in which region user is and set the languages.
Hope this helps.!

Comment: How could we change app language to Indian Lang (like Hindi, Marathi etc)?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the info provided by Deep Mehta, I've been mostly happy with [i18next.js](http://i18next.com/), using their AMD version [here](http://i18next.com/public/download/versions/i18next.amd-1.10.1.zip) (because I'm using JQuery / Backbone in my cordova app), along with the [cordova globalization plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-globalization) you can add through the CLI:

`cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-globalization`

One thing that you need to keep in mind is that i18next's initialization AND the cordova globalization's initialization are asynchronous -- don't call into the globalization API until the DeviceReady event fires, and don't try to get localized strings until the i18next library initializes. Here is the applicable code:

```
        // app initialization code. Here we'll initialize localization with the current locale 
        initialize: function (options) {

            // callback function to initialize / load the localization info
            var initialize_i18n = function (locale) {
                i18n.init({
                    lng: locale,
                    debug: true,
                    fallbackLng: 'en'
                }, function () {
                    // NOW i18next can be used
                });
            };

            // get the user's locale - mobile or web
            // ASSUMES DeviceReady() HAS ALREADY FIRED
            if (typeof navigator.globalization !== 'undefined') {
                navigator.globalization.getLocaleName(
                    function (loc) {
                        locale = loc.value.split("-")[0];
                        initialize_i18n(locale);
                    },
                    function () {console.log('Error getting locale\n'); }
                );
            } else {
                // in web browser
                lang = (navigator.languages) ? navigator.languages[0] : (navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage);
                locale = lang.split("-")[0];
                initialize_i18n(locale);
            }
    },
    // etc.
```